# Does offset work with temp tables and the Rows command

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wanting to use the new rows and offset in the more recent versions of sql server 2014 and up but It does not appear to allow me to do it with tempory tables is this the case.

I am joining another query to this one and inserting them into a tempory table. The reason I am wanting to use the offset command was for paging but I guess it doesn't work with temp tables.

```
select st.StocktakeID, 
              bi.BinName, 
              si.ItemID as StockItemID, 
              si.Code, 
              si.Name, 
              si.Barcode, 
              si.StockUnitName,
              scsi.StocktakeCountShtItemID, 
              scsi.RecordedQuantityInStock,
              scsi.ActualQuantityEntered,
              scsi.ActualQuantityInStock
into #StockTakeItems
from #StockTakes st
join StocktakeCountSheetItem scsi on st.StocktakeID = scsi.StocktakeID
join BinItem bi on scsi.BinItemID = bi.BinItemID
join StockItem si on bi.ItemID = si.ItemID


select * from #StockTakeItems sti 
OFFSET @start Rows  
Fetch NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY 

end
GO
```

I am getting the error

> incorrect syntax near from expecting rows

But I am using 2014 on the production server and 2017 on the test server this should work in 2017 or have they removed it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add order by I assume while using offset and fetch in SQL server. I think this should work.

```
select st.StocktakeID, 
              bi.BinName, 
              si.ItemID as StockItemID, 
              si.Code, 
              si.Name, 
              si.Barcode, 
              si.StockUnitName,
              scsi.StocktakeCountShtItemID, 
              scsi.RecordedQuantityInStock,
              scsi.ActualQuantityEntered,
              scsi.ActualQuantityInStock
into #StockTakeItems
from #StockTakes st
join StocktakeCountSheetItem scsi on st.StocktakeID = scsi.StocktakeID
join BinItem bi on scsi.BinItemID = bi.BinItemID
join StockItem si on bi.ItemID = si.ItemID


select * from #StockTakeItems sti 
order  by StocktakeID
OFFSET @start Rows  
Fetch NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

You can check this link as well:

http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-offset-fetch/